# Kotlin AndroidStudio Type Mismatch inferred type

Tags: android, kotlin

I get some *error* in my code, `Type mismatch: inferred type is UserData? but UserData was expected` for the lines `val listUser : UserData = intent.getParcelableExtra(EXTRA_DATA)`

Here is my class :

```
package com.example.rifqi_submission_1

import android.os.Bundle
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.user_detail.*

class UserDetail : AppCompatActivity() {
    companion object{
        var EXTRA_DATA = "0"
    }

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.user_detail)

            val listUser : UserData = intent.getParcelableExtra(EXTRA_DATA)

        detail_avatar.setImageResource(listUser.avatar!!)
        detail_username.text = getString(R.string.username, listUser.username)
        detail_name.text = listUser.name
        detail_location.text = getString(R.string.location, listUser.location)
        detail_repository.text = getString(R.string.repository, listUser.repository)
        detail_company.text = getString(R.string.company, listUser.company)
        detail_followers.text = getString(R.string.followers, listUser.followers)
        detail_following.text = getString(R.string.following, listUser.following)
    }

}
```

I dont understand how to fix this, thanks for your attention :)

Answer (score 1):

`getParcelableExtra()` can return `null`.  So, change:

```kotlin
val listUser : UserData = intent.getParcelableExtra(EXTRA_DATA)
```

to:

```kotlin
val listUser : UserData? = intent.getParcelableExtra(EXTRA_DATA)
```

Comment: And then make sure that you check for `listUser==null` before using it.